# Applying an attribute to all parameters

Tags: powershell

I've got the following list of parameters for a SQL script. They're all mandatory, as you can see.

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$dropLoc,
[Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$manifest,
[Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$accountName,
[Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$appSqlServer,
[Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$appDatabaseName,
[Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$oltpDatabaseName,
[Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$oltpSqlServerName,
[Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$appRootURL,
[Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$AppServiceDBKey,
[Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$reportDBSqlServerName,
[Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$udmInstanceName,
[Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$reportDBDataPath,
[Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$reportDBLogPath,
[Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$maxETL
)
```

But this is really lengthy and I don't like how I set each one mandatory individually. Does Powershell have a way to set an attribute to all parameters?

Comment: You could have a second function to validate all parameters and loop through them with .$FunctionName.ParameterSets | select name. Is the powershell file setting the params or the function?

Comment: No, this is the way to do it. But this function / script will be a pain to use. Maybe you should look for some other way to pass all that mandatory information, like stored in a config file that you read in. That way the user just has to specify one parameter (the config file) and can comfortably edit that file in his / her favorite text editor.

Comment: Normally that'd be a great idea, and I'd probably do it for this. This is building that config file though, based on input from a bunch of other places that ends up being passed into this script.